# Have $emit() execute synchronously after a function in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron

I'm trying to have a boolean variable be set to false to close a menu before opening a dialog in Vue 2.

```
public saveScreens() {
    this.showThreeDotMenu = false
    this.$emit('save-screens')
}
```

I want to execute these 2 lines synchronously however I can't find anyway for the $emit to occur before the assignment is done.

I've tried extrapolating the assignment statement into it's own function setting that to async and then in saveScreens() hitting that function then .then( () => this.$emit('save-screens')) however this still doesn't work.

No matter what I have tried the Electron Message Box opens and then after it closes the boolean is set to false and the menu i have then closes.

Is there any way in which I can wait until the conditional HTML i have using v-if is done hiding and then execute a function after that?

Using Electron 1.8.8 and Vue 2.x+

Comment: *want to execute these 2 lines synchronously however I can't find anyway for the $emit to occur before the assignment is done.* 1) it is in sync 2) it is after assignment is done - no other way.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use [Vue.nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: @RoyJ that also did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any chance you could make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem? I'm not entirely clear what is happening vs. what you want to happen.

Comment: Uhm not really, I mean it's just im trying to hide an html div (containing a menu) with v-if by changing a boolean value to false, right before i open an Electron dialog ( https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog ). I dont really use Jsfiddle and am unsure if you can get electron in there? But that's all thats happening is trying to set the boolean variable that the v-if is checking to false and then emitting up to a component which executes a message box and some other irrelevant functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only straightforward solution I have come up with is to use `setTimeout` to delay the dialog display (as noted in comments, `nextTick` did not solve the problem). I made a demo snippet where you can vary the timeout interval. Somewhere around 10ms works on my browser. I would recommend using something like 50 to be pretty safe everywhere.

I would use `v-show` rather than `v-if` for something that is going to be hidden and displayed again.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showMenu: true,
    delay: 10
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog() {
      this.showMenu = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert('this is a dialog');
        this.showMenu = true;
      }, this.delay);
    }
  },
  components: {
    threeDotMenu: {
      template: '#three-dot-menu-template',
      props: ['show'],
      methods: {
        openDialog() {
          this.$emit('save-screens');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #fee;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>Delay: <input type="number" v-model="delay"></label>
  <three-dot-menu :show="showMenu" @save-screens="showDialog"></three-dot-menu>
</div>

<template id="three-dot-menu-template">
  <div class="menu" v-show="show">
    this is the menu
    <button @click="openDialog">Open dialog</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I ended up using a 25ms delay and have looked into v-show and switched this to it. Thanks for the answer it's just a bit odd to me i had to use a timeout is all.